# Aggregating cells/column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is like this

```
Index Z1       Z2       Z3       Z4  
 0    A(Z1W1)  A(Z2W1)  A(Z3W1) B(Z4W2)   
 1    A(Z1W3)  B(Z2W1)  A(Z3W2) B(Z4W3)   
 2    B(Z1W1)           A(Z3W4) B(Z4W4)
 3    B(Z1W2)
```

I want to convert it to

```
Index   Z1              Z2        Z3                    Z4
 0      A(Z1W1,Z1W3)    A(Z2W1)   A(Z3W1,Z3W2,Z3W4)     B(Z4W2,Z4W3,Z4W4)    
 1      B(Z1W1,Z1W2)    B(Z2W1)
```

Basically I want to aggregate the values of different cell to one cell as shown above

**Edit 1**

Actual column names are either two words or 3 words names and not A B 
For example Nut Butter instead of A

Comment: how many rows do you have??

Comment: The rows are dynamic They arent fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are getting interested : -)

```
s=df.stack().replace({'[(|)]':' '},regex=True).str.strip().str.split(' ',expand=True)
v=('('+s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(1),s[0]])[1].apply(','.join)+')').unstack().apply(lambda x : x.name+x.astype(str)).T
v[~v.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('None'))].apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[1865]: 
             Z1       Z2                 Z3                 Z4
0  A(Z1W1,Z1W3)  A(Z2W1)  A(Z3W1,Z3W2,Z3W4)  B(Z4W2,Z4W3,Z4W4)
1  B(Z1W1,Z1W2)  B(Z2W1)                NaN                NaN
```

Update 
Change

```
#s=df.stack().replace({'[(|)]':' '},regex=True).str.strip().str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

to

```
s=df.stack().str.split('(',expand=True)
s[1]=s[1].replace({'[(|)]':' '},regex=True).str.strip()
```

Comment: I am getting this error can you help with this sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found when i execute v= line

Comment: @Rookie_123 replace all blank to np.nan

Comment: My actual data consists of name that are not single word For example it has Nut Butter(z1W1) nut butter(z1w2) etc. Some are even 3 word names When I execute in the bracket the second letter comes up For example Nut(Butter) likewise for all others

Comment: And now answers are getting even more interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Geneal idea:

1. split string values
2. regroup and join stings
3. apply to all columns

---

Update 1

```py
# I had to add parameter as_index=False to groupby(0) 
# to get exactly same output as asked
```

Lets try one column

```py
def str_regroup(s):
return s.str.extract(r"(\w)\((.+)\)",expand=True).groupby(0,as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: '{}({})'.format(x.name,', '.join(x[1])))
str_regroup(df1.Z1)
```

output

```py
A   A(Z1W1, Z1W3)
B   B(Z1W1, Z1W2)
```

then apply to all columns

```py
df.apply(str_regroup)
```

output

```py
    Z1  Z2  Z3  Z4
0   A(Z1W1, Z1W3)   A(Z2W1) A(Z3W1, Z3W2, Z3W4) B(Z4W2, Z4W3, Z4W4)
1   B(Z1W1, Z1W2)   B(Z2W1)
```

---

Update 2
**Performance** on 100 000 sample rows

- **928 ms** for this `apply` version **;b**
- **1.55 s** for `stack()` by @Wen

Comment: Thanks for your help Got to learn a new approach for it by function

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

- [Melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) `df` to get:

  ```
  In [194]: melted = pd.melt(df, var_name='col'); melted
  Out[194]: 
     col    value
  0   Z1  A(Z1W1)
  1   Z1  A(Z1W3)
  2   Z1  B(Z1W1)
  3   Z1  B(Z1W2)
  4   Z2  A(Z2W1)
  5   Z2  B(Z2W1)
  6   Z2         
  7   Z2         
  8   Z3  A(Z3W1)
  9   Z3  A(Z3W2)
  10  Z3  A(Z3W4)
  11  Z3         
  12  Z4  B(Z4W2)
  13  Z4  B(Z4W3)
  14  Z4  B(Z4W4)
  15  Z4
  ```
- Use regex to extract `row` and `value` columns:

  ```
  In [195]: melted[['row','value']] = melted['value'].str.extract(r'(.*)\((.*)\)', expand=True); melted
  Out[195]: 
     col value  row
  0   Z1  Z1W1    A
  1   Z1  Z1W3    A
  2   Z1  Z1W1    B
  3   Z1  Z1W2    B
  4   Z2  Z2W1    A
  5   Z2  Z2W1    B
  6   Z2   NaN  NaN
  7   Z2   NaN  NaN
  8   Z3  Z3W1    A
  9   Z3  Z3W2    A
  10  Z3  Z3W4    A
  11  Z3   NaN  NaN
  12  Z4  Z4W2    B
  13  Z4  Z4W3    B
  14  Z4  Z4W4    B
  15  Z4   NaN  NaN
  ```
- Group by `col` and `row` and join the `value`s together:

  ```
  In [185]: result = melted.groupby(['col', 'row'])['value'].agg(','.join)
  In [186]: result
  Out[186]: 
  col  row
  Z1   A           Z1W1,Z1W3
       B           Z1W1,Z1W2
  Z2   A                Z2W1
       B                Z2W1
  Z3   A      Z3W1,Z3W2,Z3W4
  Z4   B      Z4W2,Z4W3,Z4W4
  Name: value, dtype: object
  ```
- Add the `row` values to the `value` values:

  ```
  In [188]: result['value'] = result['row'] + '(' + result['value'] + ')'
  In [189]: result
  Out[189]: 
      row              value
  col                       
  Z1    A       A(Z1W1,Z1W3)
  Z1    B       B(Z1W1,Z1W2)
  Z2    A            A(Z2W1)
  Z2    B            B(Z2W1)
  Z3    A  A(Z3W1,Z3W2,Z3W4)
  Z4    B  B(Z4W2,Z4W3,Z4W4)
  ```
- Overwrite the `row` column values with `groupby/cumcount` values to setup the upcoming pivot:

  ```
  In [191]: result['row'] = result.groupby(level='col').cumcount()
  In [192]: result
  Out[192]: 
       row              value
  col                        
  Z1     0       A(Z1W1,Z1W3)
  Z1     1       B(Z1W1,Z1W2)
  Z2     0            A(Z2W1)
  Z2     1            B(Z2W1)
  Z3     0  A(Z3W1,Z3W2,Z3W4)
  Z4     0  B(Z4W2,Z4W3,Z4W4)
  ```
- Pivoting produces the desired result:

  ```
  result = result.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value')
  ```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'Z1': ['A(Z1W1)', 'A(Z1W3)', 'B(Z1W1)', 'B(Z1W2)'],
 'Z2': ['A(Z2W1)', 'B(Z2W1)', '', ''],
 'Z3': ['A(Z3W1)', 'A(Z3W2)', 'A(Z3W4)', ''],
 'Z4': ['B(Z4W2)', 'B(Z4W3)', 'B(Z4W4)', '']}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3],)

melted = pd.melt(df, var_name='col').dropna()
melted[['row','value']] = melted['value'].str.extract(r'(.*)\((.*)\)', expand=True)
result = melted.groupby(['col', 'row'])['value'].agg(','.join)
result = result.reset_index('row')
result['value'] = result['row'] + '(' + result['value'] + ')'
result['row'] = result.groupby(level='col').cumcount()
result = result.reset_index()
result = result.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value')
print(result)
```

yields

```
col            Z1       Z2                 Z3                 Z4
row                                                             
0    A(Z1W1,Z1W3)  A(Z2W1)  A(Z3W1,Z3W2,Z3W4)  B(Z4W2,Z4W3,Z4W4)
1    B(Z1W1,Z1W2)  B(Z2W1)                NaN                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again a new approach for the same problem People like you make Stackoverflow just awesome :)